# NumPy scalars, broadcasting and the __iadd__ method

Tags: python, numpy

Any ideas on this oddity?

```
from numpy import *

a = array([1,2])
b = 1
b += a
```

gives `array([2,3])`, as you would expect. But

```
a = array([1,2])
b = array(1)
b += a
```

gives the error "non-broadcastable output operand with shape () doesn't match the broadcast shape (2)".  At the same time

```
a = array([1,2])
b = array(1)
b = b + a
```

gives `array([2,3])`.  Is this behaviour as odd as it looks at first glance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+=` operator is taken to mean "in-place summation". Numpy imposes some constraints as to what in-place means: it cannot change the size or dtype of the array. When you do `b = b + a` there is no problem, because `b` now points to a new object resulting from adding `b` and `a`, which is a length 2 array. It is not surprise that `b += a` fails, since the length 2 array cannot be fitted into the length 1 array.

As for your first test case, my guess is that since Python ints are [immutable](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) objects, whenever you `__iadd__` to one, you are effectively creating a new object and pointing to it, not modifying the object you had, so there is no reason why it shouldn't work with an array.